# Access Token Security

Tags: angular, security, websecurity

I have Angular app, which is getting access token from identity server.
I need help to find out, what all security related measure i can take.
The javascript library i am using seems that it support only local storage and Session storage at client side.

I need to implement some security measure at least below areas.

1- Storing access token at client side(angular SPA).
2- Sending Access token to access API in header.

Currently, i think it has so many security vulnerabilities.

Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: What library do you use? In all cases, you are better off relying on a professionnal vendor if you don't want to dive and maintain specific stuff. Such as Auth0 or Okta services. In any case, this question is too broad for StackOverflow

Comment: A good read with links & explanations https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209174/is-localstorage-a-security-liability-for-jwts. There are many others

Comment: I am using Azure AD as identity service and MSAL art SPA end to interact with it. Seems like MSAL only support localstorage and sessionstorage. I am thinking how secure is this and if this is right way to store token.